# In bash, how to delay interpolation of a variable that has a dynamic variable within its string

Tags: bash

I want to know how to get a string variable containing a variable in the string to interpolate the contained variable dynamically --each time it is referenced.

This is best explained with example code.

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="string of var1 $VAR2"

function function1()
{
  echo "$1 $VAR1"
}

function function2()
{
  VAR2="$1"
}

function2 1000

function1 "example 1:"

function2 2000

function1 "example 2:"
```

The output is:

```
example 1: string of var1
example 2: string of var1
```

But the desired output is:

```
example 1: string of var1 1000
example 2: string of var1 2000
```

The problem with this is that VAR1 is evaluated only once at run-time, when the desired effect would be for it to be evaluated every time it is referenced. When the string of *VAR1* is interpolated within *function1*, *VAR2* will already have been interpolated at the variable declaration, and be empty.

Obviously this is a contrived example, but it's not too hard to imagine having a variable that changes often as part of a string literal.

I have tried escaping *VAR2* as `\$VAR2` and using hard quotes on the string literal of *VAR1*. Both result in the literal string "**string of var1 $VAR2**"

I have also tried using *eval* like `eval "echo "$1 $VAR1""` but that fails to work and starts getting tricky escaping the quotes.

Yes, I know that you can refactor the whole thing to get it to work. That is not a suitable answer to the problem.

Comment: Since you've eliminated all the suitable answers from contention...

Comment: Variables are not dynamic; their value is changes only on assignation of a new value.  If you want something dynamic, you will need a function (or alais).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DopeGhoti said in a comment, variables are not dynamic; they store static data, not instructions for generating data. If you want something that'll produce different data each time it's run, use a function, and then reference it with `$()`:

```
dynamic_thing()
{
    echo "string of dynamic_thing $VAR2"
}

function function1()
{
  echo "$1 $(dynamic_thing)"
}

function function2()
{
  VAR2="$1"
}

function2 1000

function1 "example 1:"

function2 2000

function1 "example 2:"
```

The output is:

```
example 1: string of dynamic_thing 1000
example 2: string of dynamic_thing 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR1='string of var1 $VAR2'
function function1()
{
  eval echo \"'$1 $VAR1'\"
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me using Bash 4.1.2(1)-release.

Comment: @typedeaf Sorry, wrong quoting